# Swing JList, to show only 15 records

Tags: java, arrays, swing, queue, jlist

I'm making some kind of control panel with a real time log.
Real time log supposed to show last 15 logins. If there are more than 15 records, then I want last record to be deleted and the on which occured recently to be show at the top of a list. I will use observer to update log list if login or logout occurs. Should I use Queue array or is it possible to make it with swing? If possible, then how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  thinks you should use this method `setVisibleRowCount(int visibleRowCount)` in order to  Sets the preferred number of rows in the Jlist that can be displayed .

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems that it doesn't work..

Comment: as you told you get the records from DB, so you can select the 15 new recodrs from DB  !

Comment: in order to do that use this Query : SELECT TOP 15 .... ; (this syntax for MS SQLSERVER).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Make your own Tablemodel, perhaps derived from **javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel**

Just make sure your model only ever exposes 15 rows (maybe use a `LinkedList<>` to hold your log entries).

Comment: Hm, but for example, if my model contains more than 15 rows, it won't work?
I actually take records from DB, maybe there is some statement to select only last 15 records from DB?

Comment: A `TableModel` is an abstract view into some arbitrary data. Say you have 1 Million log records in a `List`. If your models `getRowCount()` only says 15 (and the associated `getValueAt()` method only returns the last 15 rows data), your JTable will only show 15 rows! Note this does not say much about how you retrieve and store your log records, so for log data in a database the "select with limit" approach also fits.

Comment: Thanks, I made it to work propertly, as you mentioned before, setting limit to 15.